# Entity Framework : load database from text files

Tags: entity-framework

I need to load object to my database from .txt files. But Im frankly a little bit lost on where to begin, and running out of time.
for example I have this file, where the "@" is the separator between the column values.

```
1@1@5@Fotocopia Cedula
1@2@5@Pedido de Antecedentes
2@3@5@Licencia de Contruccion
2@4@5@Permiso de Ruidos
3@5@1@Recibo Multa
4@6@5@Reserva volqueta
5@7@6@pedir cedula o algo asi
5@8@2@etapa Alternativa
6@9@6@pedir cedula o algo asi
7@10@6@pedir cedula o algo asi
7@11@1@pedir cedula o algo asi
8@12@4@pedir cedula o algo asi
9@13@6@pedir cedula o algo asi
9@14@2@segunda etp
```

this is the corresponding class on my project

```
 public class Etapa
    {
        //este tiene que ser autogenerado
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Codigo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Lapso dias Etapa no se puede dejar vacío")]
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "El valor debe ser mayor que {0}")]
        //Cambiar el nombre que se desplegará en el formulario
        [DisplayName("Lapso dias Etapa")]
        public int LapsoMaximoDias { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La Descripcion Etapa no se puede dejar vacía")]
        //Cambiar el nombre que se desplegará en el formulario
        [DisplayName("Descripcion Etapa")]
        //Indicar largo maximo y minimo
        [StringLength(50,MinimumLength =3)]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I extract the data, and save them as entities of this class?
I want to have a method that I can call with a button, so it can load all the data from those files every time I want it (or update them)
Tks for your time, sorry if it's a broad question.

Comment: Start with importing the delimited file. Here are a couple examples: https://forums.asp.net/t/2059487.aspx?how+to+read+the+text+file+with+pipe+delimited+in+c+and+put+data+in+datatable

Comment: tks, I will strart with that.